# Работа с драйвером

Tags: c#, .net, драйвер

Есть драйвер (два файла с расширением .sys и .inf), как с ним правильно работать в с#? Нужно с помощью драйвера LPTWDMIO управлять lpt портом. Есть пример работы с этим драйвером на Delphi,больше никаких примеров нет, а сам я далек от системного программирования (да и c# начал изучать недавно)

Это класс для работы драйвером :

```
===========================================================================
 Bugtrack:

 25.08.2002 -- Добавлены деклараторы для описания отдельных бит в регистрах LPT,
 Добавлена секция для самозагрузки драйвера под Windows NT/2000/XP

 27.08.2002 -- Добавлена поддержка регистров данных и адреса EPP и поддержка
 прямого ввода-вывода на платформах Windows 9X.

 01.02.2003 -- Исправлена ошибка в процедурах Writepk и Readpk (цикл по структурам)

 14.04.2002 -- Исправлена ошибка в функции IsPortBidirectional

 ===========================================================================}
unit LPTIO;

interface
 uses Windows, SysUtils, Forms;

 const
 { Имя символuческой связи }
 DRV_LINK_NAME : string = '\\.\LptAccessAgent';

 { Коды сообщений драйверу }
 IOCTL_READ_PORTS  : cardinal = $00220050; // Чтение регистров LPT
 IOCTL_WRITE_PORTS : cardinal = $00220060; // Запись в регистры LPT

 { Номера портов LPT }
 LPT1 : byte = $10; // база $3BC
 LPT2 : byte = $20; //      $378
 LPT3 : byte = $30; //      $278

 { Смещения регистров порта }
 LPT_DATA_REG    : byte = 0; // Регистр данных
 LPT_STATE_REG   : byte = 1; // Регистр состояния
 LPT_CONTROL_REG : byte = 2; // Регистр управления
 LPT_EPP_ADDRESS : byte = 3; // Регистр адреса EPP
 LPT_EPP_DATA    : byte = 4; // Регистр данных EPP

 { Битовые расклады регистров / разъём 25 pin / разъём Centronic }
 { Битовый расклад регистра УПРАВЛЕНИЯ }
 STROBE    : byte = $01; { Строб,          1 /1             }
 AUTOFEED  : byte = $02; { Автопротяжка,   14/14            }
 INIT      : byte = $04; { Инициализация,  16/31            }
 SELECTIN  : byte = $08; { Выбор принтера, 17/36            }
 IRQE      : byte = $10; { Прерывание,     ------           }
 DIRECTION : byte = $20; { Направление ШД, ------           }

 { Битовый расклад регистра СОСТОЯНИЯ }
 IRQS      : byte = $04; { Флаг прерывания,------           }
 ERROR     : byte = $08; { Признак ошибки, 15/32            }
 SELECT    : byte = $10; { Признак выбора, 13/13            }
 PAPEREND  : byte = $20; { Конец бумаги,   12/12            }
 ACK       : byte = $40; { Готовность к приёму данных, 10/10}
 BUSY      : byte = $80; { Занятость,      11/11            }

 SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS : cardinal = $000F003F;
 SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS    : cardinal = $000F01FF;

 SWC_NAME         : string = 'lptwdmio';        { Системное имя сервиса }
 SWC_DISPLAY_NAME : string = 'LPT port direct access service'; { Название сервиса, чтобы показать пользователю :) }

 type
 { Структура Адрес-Данные }
 ADRDATASTRUCT = record
  Adr  : byte; { адрес == <Номер порта> or <Смещение регистра>      }
  Data : byte; { данные для вывода или место для прочитанного байта }
                 end;
 PADRDATASTRUCT = ^ADRDATASTRUCT;

 SC_HANDLE = cardinal; // Тип хэндла для обращения к менеджеру сервисов

 POpenSCManager = function (lpMachineName, lpDatabaseName: PChar;
                            dwDesiredAccess: DWORD): SC_HANDLE; stdcall;

 PCloseServiceHandle = function (hSCObject: SC_HANDLE): BOOL; stdcall;

 PCreateService = function (hSCManager: SC_HANDLE;
                            lpServiceName, lpDisplayName : PChar;
                            dwDesiredAccess, dwServiceType, dwStartType, dwErrorControl : DWORD;
                            lpBinaryPathName, lpLoadOrderGroup : PChar;
                            lpdwTagId : LPDWORD;
                            lpDependencies, lpServiceStartName, lpPassword: PChar): SC_HANDLE; stdcall;

 PStartService = function (hService: SC_HANDLE; dwNumServiceArgs: DWORD;
                           var lpServiceArgVectors: PChar): BOOL; stdcall;

 POpenService  = function (hSCManager: SC_HANDLE; lpServiceName: PChar;
                           dwDesiredAccess: DWORD): SC_HANDLE; stdcall;

 PDeleteService = function (hService: SC_HANDLE): BOOL; stdcall;

 TLptPortConnection = class
  private
  hdrv  : cardinal; // Хэндл загруженного драйвера
  winnt : boolean;  // Признак платформы NT

  UnregisterService   : boolean;    // флаг, показывающий необходимость удаления сервиса lptwdmio по закрытии приложения в Win NT
  hdll                : cardinal;            // Хэндл библиотеки advapi32.dll
  SysBinaryName       : AnsiString;          // Имя файла драйвера
  ServiceArgVectors   : PChar;               // Вспомогательная переменная для вызова StartService
  OpenSCManager_      : POpenSCManager;      // Указатель на ф-ю OpenSCManager Win32 API
  CloseServiceHandle_ : PCloseServiceHandle; // -//- CloseServiceHandle
  CreateService_      : PCreateService;      // -//- CreateService
  StartService_       : PStartService;       // -//- StartService
  OpenService_        : POpenService;        // -//- OpenService
  DeleteService_      : PDeleteService;      // -//- DeleteService

  // Флаги наличия портов
  PortPresent : array [0..2] of Boolean;

  procedure Writepk(Addr : WORD; Data : byte);

  function  Readpk(Addr : WORD) : byte;


  public
  constructor Create;            // Конструктор
  destructor  Destroy; override; // Деструктор

  function    Ready : boolean; // Возвращает признак готовности/неготовности

  function    IsNtPlatform : boolean;

  function    IsPortPresent(LptNumber : byte) : boolean;

  function    IsPortBidirectional(LptNumber : byte) : boolean;


  // Функция для чтения регистров LPT. Возвращает true, если чтение прошло успешно.
  // PairArray -- массив структур ADRDATASTRUCT, в которые будут считываться данные из портов.
  //  Члены Adr должны быть инициализированы значениями (<Номер порта LPT>or<Смещение регистра>),
  //  например: PairArray[i].Adr := LPT1 or LPT_STATE_REG;
  //
  // PairCount -- количество структур в массиве PairArray.
  function    ReadPorts (PairArray : PADRDATASTRUCT; PairCount : cardinal) : boolean;

  // Функция для вывода данных в регистры LPT. Возвращает true, если запись прошла успешно.
  // PairArray -- см. выше, + члены Data структур ADRDATASTRUCT должны содержать данные для вывода
  //  в соответствующие регистры порта.
  // PairCount -- см. выше.
  function    WritePorts(PairArray : PADRDATASTRUCT; PairCount : cardinal) : boolean;

  // Функция для чтения одного регистра указанного порта
  function    ReadPort  (LptNumber : byte; RegOffset : byte) : byte;

  // Процедура для вывода значения в регистр порта
  procedure   WritePort (LptNumber : byte; RegOffset : byte; Value : byte);

  // Процедура для выполнения задержки
  // Time -- величина задержки в мкс. Допустимые значения - от 0 до 50 мкс.
  procedure   Delay(Time : Cardinal);

                      end; {class}
 PLptPortConnection = ^TLptPortConnection;


implementation


// Конструктор
constructor TLptPortConnection.Create;
var
 osv            : OSVERSIONINFO; // Структура для получения версии платформы
 hSCMahager     : SC_HANDLE;     // Хэндл менеджера сервисов
 hServiceHandle : SC_HANDLE;     // Хэндл сервиса lptwdmio
begin
 inherited Create;
 // Первичная инициализация
 hdrv := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 UnregisterService:=false;
 hdll := 0;

 osv.dwOSVersionInfoSize:=sizeof(osv);
 GetVersionEx(osv);
 winnt:=(osv.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT); // NT-я или нет?

 SetLastError(NO_ERROR);
 hdrv := CreateFile(PChar(DRV_LINK_NAME),
                    GENERIC_READ    or GENERIC_WRITE,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    nil,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    0);

 if hdrv=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  if winnt then // Не удалось связаться с драйвером. Он не был установлен вручную.
  begin
   // Windows NT -- пробуем запустить драйвер через менеджер управления сервисами
   hdll := LoadLibrary(PChar('ADVAPI32.DLL')); // Получим указатели на ф-и менеджера сервисов.
   if hdll<>0 then
   begin

    OpenSCManager_      := POpenSCManager(GetProcAddress(hdll,PChar('OpenSCManagerA')));
    CloseServiceHandle_ := PCloseServiceHandle(GetProcAddress(hdll,PChar('CloseServiceHandle')));
    CreateService_      := PCreateService(GetProcAddress(hdll,PChar('CreateServiceA')));
    StartService_       := PStartService (GetProcAddress(hdll,PChar('StartServiceA' )));
    OpenService_        := POpenService  (GetProcAddress(hdll,PChar('OpenServiceA'  )));
    DeleteService_      := PDeleteService(GetProcAddress(hdll,PChar('DeleteService' )));

    hSCMahager:=OpenSCManager_(nil,nil,SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if 0<>hSCMahager then
    begin 
     SysBinaryName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'LPTWDMIO.SYS'; // имя бинарника sys
     hServiceHandle := CreateService_(hSCMahager,
                                      PChar(SWC_NAME),          // имя сервиса
                                      PChar(SWC_DISPLAY_NAME),  // отображаемое имя
                                      SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,       // права доступа
                                      1,                        // SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER
                                      3,                        // SERVICE_DEMAND_START
                                      1,                        // SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
                                      PChar(SysBinaryName),
                                      nil,
                                      nil,
                                      nil,
                                      nil,
                                      nil);
     if 0=hServiceHandle then
     begin 
      hServiceHandle := OpenService_(hSCMahager,PChar(SWC_NAME),SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS); // откроем его
     end;
     if 0<>hServiceHandle then
     begin // ОК, запускаем сервис
      ServiceArgVectors := nil;
      StartService_(hServiceHandle,0,ServiceArgVectors); 
      UnregisterService:=true;             
      CloseServiceHandle_(hServiceHandle); 
     end;

     CloseServiceHandle_(hSCMahager); 
    end;
   end;


   SetLastError(NO_ERROR);
   hdrv := CreateFile(PChar(DRV_LINK_NAME),
                      GENERIC_READ    or GENERIC_WRITE,
                      FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                      nil,
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                      0);
  end;

 if Ready() then
 begin

  PortPresent[0] := IsPortPresent(LPT1);
  PortPresent[1] := IsPortPresent(LPT2);
  PortPresent[2] := IsPortPresent(LPT3);
 end;
end;

destructor  TLptPortConnection.Destroy;
var
 hSCMahager     : SC_HANDLE;
 hServiceHandle : SC_HANDLE;
begin
 if hdrv<>INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then CloseHandle(hdrv);
 if UnregisterService and winnt then
 begin // разрегистрировать сервис
  if hdll<>0 then
  begin
   hSCMahager:=OpenSCManager_(nil,nil,SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS); 
   if 0<>hSCMahager then
   begin
    hServiceHandle := OpenService_(hSCMahager,PChar(SWC_NAME),SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS); 
    if hServiceHandle<>0 then
    begin
     DeleteService_(hServiceHandle);      
     CloseServiceHandle_(hServiceHandle); 
    end;
    CloseServiceHandle_(hSCMahager); 
   end;
  FreeLibrary(hdll); 
  end;
 end;
 inherited Destroy;
end;

function    TLptPortConnection.Ready : boolean;
begin
 Ready := ( hdrv <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) or not winnt; // Либо загружен драйвер, либо Windows 9x
end;

// Функция для чтения регистров LPT. Возвращает true, если чтение прошло успешно.
function    TLptPortConnection.ReadPorts (PairArray : PADRDATASTRUCT; PairCount : cardinal) : boolean;
var
 cb   : cardinal;
 Pair : PADRDATASTRUCT;
 ct   : cardinal;
 adr  : WORD;
begin
 if Ready() then
  begin
   if hdrv <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
   begin // Чтение через драйвер
    cb:=0; SetLastError(NO_ERROR);
    DeviceIoControl( hdrv,
                     IOCTL_READ_PORTS,
                     PairArray,PairCount*2,
                     PairArray,PairCount*2,
                     cb,
                     nil );
    ReadPorts := (NO_ERROR = GetLastError());
   end else
   begin // Чтение напрямую через обращения к портам (Windows 9x)
    Pair:=PairArray;
    for ct:=0 to PairCount-1 do
    begin // Цикл по переданным структурам
     adr := $278; // LPT3 по умолчанию
     case (Pair.Adr shr 4) of
      1:  adr := $3BC; // LPT1
      2:  adr := $378; // LPT2
     end; // case
     adr := adr + (7 and Pair.Adr); // База + смещение
     Pair.Data:=Readpk(adr); // Читать данные
     inc(Pair);
    end; // for
    ReadPorts:=true;
   end;
  end       else
  begin
   ReadPorts:=false;
  end;
end;

// Функция для вывода данных в регистры LPT. Возвращает true, если запись прошла успешно.
function    TLptPortConnection.WritePorts(PairArray : PADRDATASTRUCT; PairCount : cardinal) : boolean;
var
 cb   : cardinal;
 Pair : PADRDATASTRUCT;
 ct   : cardinal;
 adr  : WORD;
begin
 if Ready() then
  begin
   if hdrv <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
   begin // Запись через драйвер
    cb:=0; SetLastError(NO_ERROR);
    DeviceIoControl( hdrv,
                     IOCTL_WRITE_PORTS,
                     PairArray,PairCount*2,
                     PairArray,PairCount*2,
                     cb,
                     nil );
    WritePorts := (NO_ERROR = GetLastError());
   end else
   begin // Запись через прямые обращения к портам (Windows 9x)
    Pair:=PairArray;
    for ct:=0 to PairCount-1 do
    begin // Цикл по переданным структурам
     adr := $278; // LPT3 по умолчанию
     case (Pair.Adr shr 4) of
      1:  adr := $3BC; // LPT1
      2:  adr := $378; // LPT2
     end; // case
     adr := adr + (7 and Pair.Adr); // База + смещение
     Writepk(adr,Pair.Data); // Вывести данные
     inc(Pair);
    end; // for
    WritePorts:=true;
   end;
  end       else
  begin
   WritePorts:=false;
  end;
end;

// Функция для чтения одного регистра указанного порта
function    TLptPortConnection.ReadPort  (LptNumber : byte; RegOffset : byte) : byte;
var Pair : ADRDATASTRUCT;
begin
 Pair.Adr  := LptNumber or RegOffset;
 Pair.Data := 0;
 ReadPorts(@Pair,1);
 ReadPort:=Pair.Data;
end;

// Процедура для вывода значения в регистр порта
procedure   TLptPortConnection.WritePort (LptNumber : byte; RegOffset : byte; Value : byte);
var Pair : ADRDATASTRUCT;
begin
 Pair.Adr  := LptNumber or RegOffset;
 Pair.Data := Value;
 WritePorts(@Pair,1);
end;

function    TLptPortConnection.IsNtPlatform : boolean;
begin
 IsNtPlatform:=winnt;
end;

// Ф-я тестирования наличия порта. Возвратит true, если порт присутствует.
function    TLptPortConnection.IsPortPresent(LptNumber : byte) : boolean;
var
 data    : byte;
 present : boolean;
begin
 present := true;
 data:=ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG); // Сохраняем текущее значение регистра данных
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG,$00); // Пишем 0
 present := present and ($00=ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG)); // Проверим -- что записали, то и прочитали?
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG,$55); // Пишем $55
 present := present and ($55=ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG));
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG,$AA); // Пишем $AA
 present := present and ($AA=ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG));
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_DATA_REG,data); // Восстанавливаем прежнее значение регистра данных
 // Проверим наличие регистров управления и данных, если порт не обнаружен (в случае однонаправленного порта)
 if not present then
 begin
  data := ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG);            // Читаем регистр управления
  present := (data<>$00) and (data<>$FF); // Не пустое значение? -- порт присутствует
  if not present then
  begin
   data := ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_STATE_REG);             // Читаем регистр состояния
   present := (data<>$00) and (data<>$FF);
  end;
 end;
 IsPortPresent := present;
end;

// Ф-я тестирования порта на двунаправленность
function    TLptPortConnection.IsPortBidirectional(LptNumber : byte) : boolean;
var
 data  : byte;
 bidir : boolean;
begin
 bidir := true;
 data := ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG); // Читаем регистр управления
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG,data or DIRECTION);     // Устанавливаем бит направления (DIR)
 bidir := bidir and (DIRECTION = (DIRECTION and ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG)));
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG,data and (not DIRECTION)); // Снимаем бит направления (DIR)
 bidir := bidir and (DIRECTION <> (DIRECTION and ReadPort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG)));
 WritePort(LptNumber,LPT_CONTROL_REG,data);   // Восстанавливаем прежнее значение регистра данных
 IsPortBidirectional := bidir;
end;

{ Процедура вывода данных в порт ПК для Windows 9x }
procedure TLptPortConnection.Writepk(Addr : WORD; Data : byte);
begin
 asm
  push eax
  push edx
  mov dx,Addr
  mov al,Data
  out dx,al
  pop edx
  pop eax
 end;
end;

{ Процедура ввода данных из порта ПК для Windows 9x }
function  TLptPortConnection.Readpk(Addr : WORD) : byte;
var
 value : byte;
begin
 asm
  push eax
  push edx
  mov dx,Addr
  in al,dx
  mov value,al
  pop edx
  pop eax
 end;
 Readpk:=value;
end;

// Процедура для выполнения задержки
// Time -- величина задержки в мкс. Допустимые значения - от 0 до 50 мкс.
procedure   TLptPortConnection.Delay(Time : Cardinal);
var
 ct  : cardinal;
 ads : ADRDATASTRUCT;
begin
 ct := Time;
 if (ct>50) then ct:=50;
 ct := (ct+ct+ct) shr 1; // *1.5, ибо одно чтение из порта -- это примерно 0.6 .. 1.2 мкс на большинстве машин,  независимо от частоты пня и сист. шины.
 if (ct=0) then ct:=1;
 if (PortPresent[0]) then // выбираем порт, из которого будем читать
 begin
  ads.Adr := LPT1 or LPT_DATA_REG;
 end else
 begin
  if (PortPresent[1]) then
  begin
   ads.Adr := LPT2 or LPT_DATA_REG;
  end else
  begin
   ads.Adr := LPT3 or LPT_DATA_REG;
  end;
 end;
 while ct<>0 do
 begin
  ReadPorts(@ads,1);
  dec(ct);
 end;
end;


end.
```

---

тот ответ меня всем устроил))) но  не было доступа к устройству которым нужно управлять,  реализовал архитектуру и кучу разных  фич, но сроки горят, так хоть что то перед глазами

Comment: Можно уточнить вопрос? И что именно нужно выполнять?

Comment: С помощью P/Invoke, разумеется. А как вы управляете им в C? Дайте код, попробуем перевести.

Comment: Подойдет и делфи :-) так или иначе, переводить код придется

Comment: А чем Вас не устроил [этот][0] ответ? 

[0]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/206628/c-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-lpt-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Ох, какая простыня. Вы ведь не хотите заставить нас читать её _всю_? Лучше вы начните переделывать это в C#-класс (константы вы уж сами переделаете, правильно?), а конкретную конструкцию, которую не получается перевести, выложите на всеобщее обозрение.